# What command should supersede \DeclareRobustCommand?

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing, robust-commands

In section 6.1 of `clsguide.pdf` (link: `https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clsguide`), under "Commands superseded for new material", the class guide lists the command `\DeclareRobustCommand` and `\DeclareRobustCommand*` as commands that "are widely used but have been superseded by more modern methods."

My question is, then, what commands are best used in place of the aforementioned commands? Unless I'm mistaken, the class guide doesn't provide this information. In `source2e.pdf`, `\DeclareRobustCommand` is used quite often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The engine-robust command set `\NewDocumentCommand`, etc., are now the recommended method for creating document commands. These are documented in `usrguide`.

Comment: Is `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends recommended even if the created document command has zero arguments?

Comment: @User23456234 If it's a command (so containing non-expandable material), then yes